# Qt - Using QEasingCurve's output for something other than an Animation

Tags: c++, qt

I wonder could anyone be of help.

If for example I wanted to use the output of the QEasingcurve for another purpose other than driving a QAnimation, is this possible? For example, if I had a numerical read out on my GUI that I wanted to grow, overshoot and bounce back into place could I use the QEasingcurve for this purpose?

I have used Qt for quite a while but have never dabbled with any of these parts of it - I am trying to work it out but cannot, so thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand correctly what you want to display, but from what I understand, using [`QPropertyAnimation`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qpropertyanimation.html) is probably the way to go.

However, to answer your question, you can of course use [`QEasingCurve`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qeasingcurve.html) in a standalone manner, you just need to use the [`valueForProgress(qreal progress)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qeasingcurve.html#valueForProgress) member function.

Comment: Thanks - I want to use it to control the position of a Gauge element. I have one of the Qt SVG Gauge's in place and it is controlled by simply updating the position of the gauge needle. I wanted to make the gauge seem a bit more realistic by giving it an overshoot and bounce. I'll play with what you suggested there and see what I can come up with.

Comment: From what I saw in `qtsvdialgauge.h`, the actual value of the gauge is not a property (it seems a bit odd, since `minimum`, `maximum`, `startAngle` and `endAngle` are all properties...) and hence can't be animated using `QPropertyAnimation`...I guess you'll have to animate it yourself then.

Answer (score 1):

Hey - Just wanted to update with how I carried this out in case anyone looks it up in the future.

```
void RPM::updateGauge(float speed)
{
  easing = new QEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutElastic);

  easing->setAmplitude(1.0);

  currentPosition = (float)ui->svgdial_currentSpeed->value();
  newPosition = speed;
  difference = newPosition - currentPosition;

  interval = 0.0;

  timer = new QTimer(this);

  connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doGaugeMovement()));

  timer->start(60);

}

void RPM::doGaugeMovement()
{
  interval+=0.01;
  ui->svgdial_currentSpeed->setValue(currentPosition + ( difference * easing-
                                           >valueForProgress( interval ) ) );


 if(interval >= 1.0)
 {
     timer->stop();
 }

}
```

Simply used a timer to update the gauge slowly, pulling the valueForProgress result for its new position each time.